# JavaScript bad syntax while importing Moment.js

Tags: javascript

I need to import Moment.js so I add first script and then importing:

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/moment.js" type="moment"></script>
<script>
    import moment from 'moment';
</script>
```

I always get error: **import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

Thanks for help.

Comment: `type="moment"`?!

Comment: You can only use `import` syntax in code that is declared to be a module, not in normal scripts.

Comment: I am using this import for first time so I don't know how works type with import.

Comment: And what to do if I want it import in normal scripts?

Comment: should that be `type="module"` - since you're using `import`

Comment: @PeterValek You'll want to start reading some tutorials then, like https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: @PeterValek In normal scripts, you just can't use modules. But probably moment.js doesn't use ES6 module format anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import lib in the browser environment.
You referred the lib source and after the DOM is loaded the moment object just will be in the global scope.
Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/rLjQx/)

```
var now = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm A');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/)

This is how to use moment in the browser

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const today = moment()
  console.log(`Today's  date is ${today.format('DD MM YYYY')}`)
  const tomorrow = today.add(1, 'days')
  console.log(`Tomorrow is ${tomorrow.format('dddd')}`)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) docs:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```